# Is it possible and Edit an outgoing HTTP Request

Tags: http, networking, request, wireshark

Can you block/stop and edit an outgoing HTTP Request and then send it on its way ?

For Example, if I make a `HTTP GET` Request to my Website, could I edit the `user-agent` header from something like

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135`
to
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/537.36`

I have tried to do this in wireshark, but I have not yet been successful, becuause I dont use wireshark regularly.

Comment: Well, one way is coding the request by hand or use a library that emulates a browser and allows you to make customize the requests . But that does not involve intercepting and altering a HTTP request.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple if you use Proxyman (https://proxyman.io) instead of Wireshark or Fiddler.

Using the Scripting tool that allows you to change the Request's Header

Here is how you can define a rule and change the User-Agent

[image: Change Request Header with Proxyman]

Code:

```js
function onRequest(context, url, request) {

  // Update or Add new headers
  request.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/537.36";

  // Done
  return request;
}
```

Snippet Code that you can copy&paste: https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/snippet-code

Answer (score 1):

### Configure browser

Modern browsers include lots of tools, which might help you in changing the necessary parts of the next request you do. E.g. user-agent can be easily changed in Mozilla by creating/adjusting `general.useragent.override` in `about:config`, chrome allows doing this from dev tools > network conditions, check more on [howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/)

### Use addons

Lots of browser addons are created for web developers including those, which change parts of request. I did some experiments with changing HTTP referer some time ago, there are some addons for changing user-agent, so feel free to search for one you need.

### Use curl

`curl` is quite powerful tool for manual fabricating of HTTP requests. You are looking for `curl --user-agent "user-agent-name-here" URL`, but you might also want to include other options like `--cookie "NAME=value"` etc. This way is less user-friendly, but have much more possibilities than the first two.

### Capture and replay traffic

If all ways above aren't sufficient, you can use wireshark/tcpdump to capture client-server communication, filter clients packets, modify them as you wish (e.g. in [Colasoft Packet Builder](https://www.colasoft.com/packet_builder/)), then resend modified traffic. This way is harsh with lots of pitfalls:

- TCP checksum in modified packets needs to be fixed before resending. Probably, resending tool should be capable, alternatively try `tcprewrite --fixcsum` in Linux.
- impossible to do with TLS
- hard/impossible to do properly with [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) or any time-based fields
- you will have to interpret server answers on your own, as they won't reach browser
- re-sending can fail due to numerous reasons (e.g. port is still occupied by browser; some fields have incorrect values like content length in modified packet; packets contain outdated data like no cookie when client is supposed to have one etc)

This is kind of expert mode, but what you send is limited only by your own fantasy. The only more expert mode is writing your own client to send data you want.